# Get value of live data

Tags: android, android-room, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am using Room, ViewModel and two-way databinding. In this simple example I need to select data from database and validate it. If data are valid then expose it to databinding. In the other case I have to select other data from database.

DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface IDAOQuestion {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Question WHERE questionId = :questionId")
    Question selectQuestion(long qeustionId);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long questionId;

    @NonNull
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> correct = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public int getCorrectValue() {
        return correct.getValue() == null ? 0 : correct.getValue();
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class QuestionViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    public LiveData<Question> mLDQuestion = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void getQuestion(int questionId) {
        //pseudo DAO access
        Question question = IDAOQuestion.selectQuestion(questionId);

        //here it is always true (question.getCorrectValue() returns 0)
        if(question.getCorrectValue() == 0) {
            getQuestion(questionId + 1);
        } else {
            mLDQuestion.setValue(question);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have type converter to convert int from database to LiveData of entity.

```
public class LiveDataIntegerTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static int toInteger(LiveData<Integer> value) {
        if (value == null || value.getValue() == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return value.getValue();
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static MutableLiveData<Integer> toObservable(int value) {
        MutableLiveData<Integer> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        liveData.postValue(value);
        return liveData;
    }
}
```

In ViewModel in the function getQuestion I have some "validation". It dowsn't work right. the code `question.getCorrectValue()` always returns 0. It is because of using MutableLiveData.postValue in TypeConverter and not existing observer on the property.

As workaround I can create another entity (POJO class) without LiveData and use it for validation. After that I can reselect data or map it to "LiveData version" of object. But this seems to be crazy and too complicated. What is the right approach to solve this?

This is just simple example. The logic is just for illustration. I understand why this is happening. Also I can't solve this by changing my SELECT query. Also I have to use the live data on my attributes because I am using it with two way databinding with depending attributes.

Comment: The entity doesn't work like that. and also `Dao` doesn't return your `LiveData`. Check [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0) link to properly understand Room and LiveData

Comment: The entity doesn't work like what? What I have wrote actually works for me but I have to use the workaround. Room doesn't return LiveData (for attributes) - this is why I implemented TypeConverter.

Comment: You should not have a `LiveData` attribute in an Entity. Ideally entities should be immutable. Also, you are creating nested `LiveDatas`, which is also an anti pattern. You have `LiveData<Question>` and `Question` itself has a `LiveData` in it. The correct solution is not to use `LiveData` in the attribute, and not to two-way-bind view and complex objects directly.

Comment: @SanlokLee I see your point. So the correct solution is to have entity without LiveData on attributes. In activity should be observer for `LiveData<Question>` from Room. In the observer I should "remap" attributes to another object (let say QuestionLD) with LiveData properties (same properties will be in Question and in QuestionLD but in QuestionLD it will be with LiveData)? When it should be saved back to database I need to make another "remap" from QuestionLD to Question? And after that I can use two-way databinding, right? If so there is so much boilerplate. Databinding should eliminate it.

Comment: There are few options you can use to get the `LiveData` value in view models (vs having observer in `Activity`). You could use `.observeForever` to observe it, or use `MediatorLiveData` to delegate source `LiveData` values to your own `LiveData`. Also, I recommend against having any data class with `LiveData` property, including `QuestionLD`. Just put `LiveData` attributes in view models and map `Question` attributes to view model. For example, there should be a `QuestionViewModel.correctValue` instead of having `QuestionViewModel.mLDQuestion.correctValue`

Comment: Ok so mapping, mapping, mapping... It is similar solution like my workaround. Instead mapping to `QuestionLD` I should map it into `ViewModel`. I understand why this is better option. But in my case I have about 10 entities (each of different type) with approximately 15 attributes in each of them in my `ViewModel`. This is the reason why I prefer `LiveData` in my data classes.

Anyway thank you. Still useful information.